# rake db:migrate gives incompatible library version error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-migrations

while executing rake db:migrate I got below error

bundle install is already executed
with success message -- Bundle complete! 102 Gemfile dependencies, 252 gems now installed.

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle (fatal)

    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/pg-0.18.4/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /Users/username/Documents/portal/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/Documents/portal/Rakefile:4:in `require'
    from /Users/username/Documents/portal/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@portal/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As per the description and the logs mentioned in the question it seems like there is a broken **PATH**
, however after going through some of the links, found the below mentioned link suggesting a bug in ruby-2.3.1.

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9760#note-14

As a quick workaround, I would suggesting installing ruby-2.3.3. Execute the below mentioned commands to install the same:

```
rvm install ruby-2.3.3
rvm gemset empty
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

It will definitely work as I also have this ruby version installed on my local machine and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your version of the postgres gem is not compatible with that version of activesupport.

Please post these files so we can get more info:
 - .ruby-version (if it exists)
 - .ruby-gemset (if it exists)
 - .rvmrc (if it exists)
 - Gemfile
 - Gemfile.lock

I'm guessing that your ActionSupport (a rails library) was upgraded, and your system's PostgreSQL can't be upgraded to the version that the postgres Gem your app depends on needs.